# Redirect to previous URL after successful authentication NextAuth

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-auth

I have implemented next auth using credentials provider.

```js
export const authOptions = {
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt"
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: {
          label: "Email",
          type: "email",
          placeholder: "zayd@consulting.ae"
        },
        password: {
          label: "Password",
          type: "password"
        }
      },

      async authorize(credentials) {
        //   handling auth request: check credentials
        if (!credentials?.email || !credentials?.password) {
          return null
        }
        const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
          where: {
            email: credentials.email
          }
        })

        // incase the user isn't there
        if (!user) {
          return null
        }

        // compare and return
        const isValidPassword = await compare(credentials.password, user.password)
        if (!isValidPassword) {
          return null
        }
        return {
          id: user.id,
          email: user.email,
          name: user.name,
        }
      }

    })
  ],
  callbacks: {
    session: ({session, token}) => {
      return {
        ...session,
        user: {
          ...session.user,
          id: token.id,
        }
      }
    },
    jwt: ({token, user}) => {
      if(user){
        return {
          ...token,
          id: user.id,
        }
      }
      return token
    }
  }
}

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions)
export {handler as GET, handler as POST}
```

But if a user hit a protecte route `/dashboard` he will be redirected to  signin page once authenticated i need him to go where he was heading. In my redirect I'm passing a url param to where he was heading. Where to use it to redirect after signin ?

In my redirect I'm passing a url param to where he was heading. I just don't know where to use it.